# How I transform string xml with Array of Parameters to object in .NET Core

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, xml, object

I'm getting an xml string and I need to convert this xml to a .NET object
Then, create a service to deserialize or xml. but it's not working in "parameters" prop.

Code:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "mse-response")]
public class xmlObject
{

    [XmlElement(DataType = "string", ElementName = "status-code")]
    public string StatusCode { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(DataType = "string", ElementName = "profile")]
    public string Profile { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(DataType = "string", ElementName = "transaction-id")]
    public string TransactionId { get; set; }

    [XmlArray(ElementName = "parameters")]
    public Item[] Parameters { get; set; }

}

public class Item
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "param-name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "param-value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Helper:

```
public class XmlHelperService 
{
    public static T XmlDeserializeFromString<T>(string xmlString)
    {
        var serializar = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        using (var reader = new StringReader(xmlString))
        {
            return (T)serializar.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

And my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<mse-response>
  <status-code>0</status-code>
  <profile>profleID</profile>
  <transaction-id>1010608241424538336</transaction-id>
  <parameters>
    <param-item>
      <param-name>INITIALDATE</param-name>
      <param-value>0608151207</param-value>
    </param-item>
    <param-item>
      <param-name>SMPP_MESSAGE_STATUS</param-name>
      <param-value>DELIVRD</param-value>
    </param-item>
    <param-item>
      <param-name>ANUM</param-name>
      <param-value>333</param-value>
    </param-item>
    <param-item>
      <param-name>BNUM</param-name>
      <param-value>1191000000</param-value>
    </param-item>
    <param-item>
      <param-name>FINALDATE</param-name>
      <param-value>0608151207</param-value>
    </param-item>
    <param-item>
      <param-name>MSGSTATUS</param-name>
      <param-value>2</param-value>
    </param-item>
  </parameters>
</mse-response>
```

Comment: When you have an array xml serialization defaults to two level of tags like parameters and parameter.  If you have only one tag then you need to use instead of [XmlArray()] [XmlElement}.  If the two tag names are not the same then you need both [XmlArray("Parameters")] and XmlArrayItem("Item")].

Answer (score 0):

1) You could use a tool to [create XSD of the xml](https://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html).

2) Once you have the XSD, you could use `xsd.exe` from Visual Studio SDK to generate C# classes from it.

The command is:

```
xsd.exe /classes /namespace:MyTest generatedXsd.xsd
```

3) the XSD or the generated classes could be added to your project, or in this test we only look into the generated class at the property `properties`, to find out how it is generated:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("param-item", IsNullable=false)]
public mseresponseParamitem[] parameters {
    get {
        return this.parametersField;
    }
    set {
        this.parametersField = value;
    }
}
```

So, **the solution** is, in the class `xmlObject` define the property `properties` with `XmlArrayItemAttribute` attribute:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "mse-response")]
public class xmlObject
{
    ...
    [XmlArrayItemAttribute("param-item", IsNullable = false)]
    public Item[] parameters { get; set; }
}
```